# 「結合セル内の値を、結合解除後に結合されていた全てのセルへコピーする方法」でなく、結合セルの最初の列へだけ、コピーする方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: vba

①結合セル内の第2,3...列目は、空文字のままにしたいです。
コピーしすぎない。行の増える方向だけへコピーする方法です。
②別法として、解除直後に第2,3...列目をクリアする。
③別法として、別マクロで、左隣のセルの値と同じなら、空文字にするでもいいと思います。
探し方が悪いのか、見つかりませんでした。
よろしくお願いします。

(参考)結合セル内の値を、結合解除後に結合されていた全てのセルへコピーする方法
https://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/5944767.html
(参考)【エクセルVBA】一瞬で結合セルを解除して値を埋めるマクロ
https://www.excelspeedup.com/ketsugoukaijyoshiteumeru/
(参考)セル結合を解除して同じ値を入力するマクロ
https://www.relief.jp/docs/excel-vba-unmerge-and-fill.html
(参考)セルの結合を解除して同じ値を入力
https://integer.exblog.jp/1726818/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

結合解除後の領域は [Range](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/vba/api/excel.range%28object%29) オブジェクトなので
左上の セルに 値を設定するのは

```
結合範囲 as Range
結合範囲.Items(1) = '値'
```

```
結合範囲 as Range
結合範囲.Cells(1,1) = '値'
```

とかすればいいと思います。
（まだ 試してないので間違ってたらごめんなさい）

Answer (score 0):

できました。ありがとうございました。

```
Sub a結合解除_1列目代入()
  Dim 範囲 As Range
  Dim 結合範囲 As Range
  Dim 結合範囲1 As Range
  Dim 値 As Variant
  For Each 範囲 In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
      If 範囲.MergeCells Then
         値 = 範囲
         Set 結合範囲 = 範囲.MergeArea
         Set 結合範囲1 = 範囲.MergeArea.Columns(1)
         範囲.UnMerge
         結合範囲1 = 値
         '結合範囲を塗りつぶし
         結合範囲.Interior.Color = rgbWhiteSmoke
      End If
  Next
End Sub
```